# Dynamic menu for a List in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

Take the example of an album containing tracks using the List module, per http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/many-ways-to-relate-orchard-things-part-3-lists

Is it possible to create a dynamic menu for the list of tracks using the navigation module? I can get it to work by adding the menu part to the track content type, but that creates a lot of steps and maintenance for content creators. The other option is with queries, but that would be too complicated for content creators.

To take it further, the ultimate goal would be to create a dynamic menu for nested lists. An example would be:

Artists: contains Albums
Albums: contained by Artists and contains Tracks
Tracks: contained by Albums

I think I could do this with Taxonomies, but the source content works a lot better with Lists.

Comment: Do you want to show that menu when you on an album page (show a tracks menu for a requested album) or when you on artist page (show a tracks menu for a requested artist)?

Comment: @AlexandrPetryakov I want to do a breadcrumb, I just realized I forgot to mention that. So on the Artists page it would show [artist]; album page [artist] [album] and track page [artist] [album] [track].